# VHDL: How can I shorten a 32bit expression?

Tags: vhdl

i have the following expression and want so shorten it down to a shorter one.

Can anyone help me?

```
architecture behavioral of mux4 is
begin
    with sel select
        y <= "a" when "00",
             "b" when "01",
             "c" when "10",
             "d" when "11",
             "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" when others;
end architecture behavioral
```

I want to avoid writing 32 time the character X.
I know that it can be replaced with another expression but i can't remember.

Comment: As it stands, this is not a complete line of VHDL can you post the full line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shorten the default expression, usually `(others => 'X')` will create a value with `X` in all unspecified members (here, all members since you haven't specified any bits explicitly.

```
architecture behavioral of mux4 is
begin
    with sel select
        y <= "a" when "00",
             "b" when "01",
             "c" when "10",
             "d" when "11",
             (others => 'X') when others;
end architecture behavioral;
```

Note : there are cases where VHDL can't determine the size of the expression from the context, so this won't always work. There is an alternative : since it's obvious you want the value to be the same size as `y`, you can create such a value filled with `'X'` very easily using the `'range` attribute, as in:

```
    with sel select
        y <= "a" when "00",
             (y'range => 'X') when others;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still missing a bit of context to fully understand what you're doing, but you can assign "others" like this:

```
architecture a of mux_example is
  signal y: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  signal sel: std_logic;
begin
  y<=x"1234ABCD" when sel='1' else (others=>'X');
end architecture ;
```

Any good?

Answer (score 0):

For filling with `'X'` where length is know, then (as user3065349 points out) this can be used:

```
(others => 'X')  -- All elements with 'X'
```

For generation of a `std_logic_vector` with specific length and value, then a qualified expression can be used like:

```
std_logic_vector'(0 to 31 => 'X')  -- 32 times 'X'
```

And for other uses, then even different values may be given at different locations:

```
std_logic_vector'(0 to 2 => 'X', 3 to 5 => 'Z', 6 to 8 => 'W')  -- "XXXZZZWWW"
```